# textFile function partitioning behave while reading a directory from local file system

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to understand how the `sc.textfile("directory")` is doing the partitioning while reading a directory.

I have a directory which contain 10 files.
`rdd1 = sc.textFile("/path/*")` if I have 10 files under the path directory then by default it is creating 10 partition that is ok but when I am supplying second argument as 11 then I am getting number of partition 20 and when passing 21 the I am getting 30 partition someone can help me to understand how it is working while I am increasing the value of second arguments

Answer (score 0):

Spark delegates this job to the Hadoop's `InputFormat.getSplits(int numSplits)` and to be more precise - `TextInputFormat`.
Where `numSplits` parameter is only a hint. Even spark calls this parameter as `minPartitions`

Now it depends on an input file format e.g.
If it compressed or not?
If it is, checks that compression codec is splittable.
Then the following logic is used:

```
long goalSize = totalSize / (numSplits == 0 ? 1 : numSplits);
long minSize = Math.max(job.getLong(FileInputFormat.SPLIT_MINSIZE, 1), minSplitSize)  
...
long blockSize = file.getBlockSize();
long splitSize = computeSplitSize(goalSize, minSize, blockSize);
```

After it, Spark filters all zero-sized splits

```
allInputSplits.filter(_.getLength > 0)
```

and creates partition per split

```
new HadoopPartition(id, i, inputSplits(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark delegates this job to the Hadoop's `InputFormat.getSplits(int numSplits)` and to be more precise - `TextInputFormat`.
Where numSplits parameter is only a hint. Even spark calls this parameter as `minPartitions`

Now it depends on an input file format e.g. If it compressed or not?
If it is, checks that compression codec is splittable.
Then the following logic is used:

```
long goalSize = totalSize / (numSplits == 0 ? 1 : numSplits);
long minSize = Math.max(job.getLong(FileInputFormat.SPLIT_MINSIZE, 1), minSplitSize)  
...
long blockSize = file.getBlockSize();
long splitSize = computeSplitSize(goalSize, minSize, blockSize);
```

After it, Spark filters all zero-sized splits

```
allInputSplits.filter(_.getLength > 0)
```

and creates partition per split

```
new HadoopPartition(id, i, inputSplits(i))
```

In `computeSplitSize`, returns maximum value of `minSize` or minimum of (`blockSize` or `goalSize`)

```
protected long computeSplitSize(long goalSize, long minSize,
                                       long blockSize) {
    return Math.max(minSize, Math.min(goalSize, blockSize));
}
```